# joomla module inside a module does not appear when set to appear in selected menus only

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a custom module which is set to show in all menus. Inside this module I have loaded a   new module position named "leftcenter" using the code below.

```
<?php 
$ad_module = &JModuleHelper::getModules( 'leftcenter' );
foreach ($ad_module as $ad_loader) {
    $_options = array( 'style' => 'xhtml');
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $ad_loader);
    }
?>
```

I can view the module assigned to this position when it is set to view in all menus but does not appear at all when it is set to show in selected menus only. Can someone help me as to why this is happening?

Comment: in the current module you are using to load the other module, does it have any other purpose?

Comment: you want to use another module functions in your custom module or you just want to show show inside that module?

Comment: i want to load different modules in the "leftcenter" position based on menu selected.@Lodder

Comment: @Tornado .I just want to display the module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
    $mods = JModuleHelper::getModules('product_page');
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mods[0]);
```

also you should give modules assignment of the menus correctly from the module manager.
that is why you don't get some menus.
If your second module is appearing only in this module then you enable your second module to all menus.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by using this line of code by putting in to you module.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="leftcenter" />
```

You will get all the module inside that module which assign to that particular position.

Comment: thanks for the help.But what i need is.I need to load a module position inside another module.Different modules can be assigned to this position which should appear only on the menus it is assigned to be displayed.Currently i am able to view the inner modules only when it is assigned to be shown in all menus. @Tornado

Comment: that's why i just said,just put it where your module you want to show all modules who are assigned to that position should displayed

Comment: sorry.this code is used to render a module position inside template.it does not work inside a module.@Tornado .Any other help will be appreciated